# How to client-side-routing with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, create-react-app

tl;dr: What changes do I need to make to the `npx create-react-app` environment to enable client-side routing with `react-router`?

#### EDIT: Answered my own question, do not use href to link to within your app, use react-router-dom 'Link'.

In more detail..

I have followed Andrew Mead's React tutorial and all went well.

His setup utilised webpack with the following inserted to the `webpack.config.js` file..

```
devServer:{
            contentBase:path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
            historyApiFallback: true
        }
```

..where `historyApiFallback: true` meant his dev-server utilised client-side routing vs server-side.

Now that I finished the bulk of the tutorial I decided to create my own app using `npx create-react-app`.

Everything is working fine, but the routing is not client-side and there is no webpack.config.js file.

I understand CSR works by serving `index.html` only and manipulating the DOM in the background.

The [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) states one way to make this work is to import `'express'` which isn't part of the create-react-app initial environment, and include some code using the variable `app`. However, I don't actually know where this file lives / should live / where to important/edit etc, or whether express is actually required and perhaps there's a way to "natively" do this without adding another module to my react package.

Here are the relevant script snippets for clarity in case I have done something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Paul.

#### index.js

```
// react imports
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// materialize imports
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import './styles/customcss.css';
// redux imports
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
// component imports
import AppRouter from './app/router';

// app render
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

#### ./app/router/

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AppMainPage from "../pages/portalPage";
import ConnectedAccountPage from "../pages/accountPage";
import ConnectedPostPage from "../pages/postPage";
import { SiteWideNavBar } from "../components/sitewide/navbar";
import { SiteWideFooter } from "../components/sitewide/footer";

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <SiteWideNavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={AppMainPage} />
        <Route path="/account" exact={true} component={ConnectedAccountPage} />
        <Route path="/post" exact={true} component={ConnectedPostPage} />
      </Switch>
      <SiteWideFooter />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

#### EDIT: package.json if relevant

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-forms-materialize-css": "^1.0.1",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: react-router is used for single page applications based on CRA, https://reactrouter.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm sorry I don't understand how that is helpful? I am aware of what react-router is, and am trying to use it extensively above. Thanks. EDIT: I realise my tl;dr may not have explained properly so that's possibly why. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, You've implemented it, can you reproduce this on a sandbox online? The code seems fine to me, also what do you mean by "routing is not client-side", it in fact should be client side, do you mean you want it to be server-side?

Comment: I am an idiot, the problem was that I was using NavItem with href="/" etc from react-materialize in my navbar and not Link from from react-router-dom. Appreciate the response. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was configured correctly, the issue was I was using `NavItem` with `href="/"` etc from `react-materialize` in my navbar and not `Link`from from `react-router-dom`.

If you are getting this issue: You should be using Link from r-r-d and for any redirects also use `props.history.push('/')`. Whilst this part wasn't relevant to my issue, if you are here you might be experiencing the same issue by trying to redirect using something other than a prop.history.push() method.